# Live copy page properties container jcr: are NOT getting synchronized from master during rollout

Tags: aem

I found an issue in my project. The page properties prefixed as jcr: and not getting rolled out.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open a vanilla AEM 6.3 instance. Open page properties for page
   /content/we-retail/language-masters/en/men
2. Change values for
   properties Page Title, Description. Save & Close

[image]

3. Goto Blueprint
   Control center for We.Retail English Language Master. viz http://localhost:4512/etc/blueprints.html?rootPath=/content/we-retail/language-masters/en

   4. Rollout
      the Men page. Then Open the page properties of live copy page
      /content/we-retail/ca/en/men and check the page properties

[image]

Expected: Both Page Title and Description should be rolled out

Actual:     Page Title gets rolled out, but Description fails to roll out.

[image]

My expectation was all page properties should get rolled out. What am I missing or do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to configuration manager in OSGI, http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr and search for **CQ MSM Content Update Action** configuration.

In this under excluded page properties, jcr:.* is excluded so, the jcr properties are not inherited from parent page.
To inherit the parent page description property, replace `jcr:.*` to `jcr:(?!(description)$)`.. This will inherit the page property description to child pages as well. Need to configure similarly for other page properties as well.

[check image for configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QJ2dC.png)

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting the OSGI configuration of RolloutManagerImpl at `/system/console/configMgr/com.day.cq.wcm.msm.impl.RolloutManagerImpl`, you'll see that by default `jcr:.*`, `sling:.*` and `cq:.*` are excluded page properties. I guess the description is stored under `jcr:description` and thus does not get rolled out.

Comment: Just by coincidence I used this OSGi config as an example for another question. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653251/is-there-a-way-to-format-multi-valued-properties-vertically-in-a-jackrabbit-file for an example how to include jcr:title and jcr:description. This is  the regex `jcr:(?!(title|description)$).*`.  All other jcr:* fields **MUST** excluded. Especially if you duplicate jcr:uuid entries in your repository - you are ruined. That will cause so strange errors, you never find out.

Comment: Thanks for this lead. I am trying this in my vanilla 6.3 instance and somehow still doesnt work on We.Retail. Do we need any specific rollout config?